# im trying to set up a kubernetes service that points to an external api that is secured with tls so needs to keep the original host header

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

i'm trying to set up the following

external user calls https://service1.mycluster.com, my cluster calls https://service1.externalservice.com and then returns the response to the user

i'm doing this to leverage istio and kubernetes thats deployed in my cluster to provide centralised access to services but some of my legacy services can't be moved into the cluster

i believe i'm going to need a service with an externalName to represent the external service but unsure how to get it to resolve the tls and keep the hostname of service1.externalservice.com so the tls will pass

any ideas would be much appreciated thanks

Currently i have the following

service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: testservice1
spec:
  externalName: https://service1.externalservice.com
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ExternalName
```

ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: xxx
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
  name: test1
spec:
  ingressClassName: xxx
  rules:
  - host: service1.mycluster.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: testservice1
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - service1.mycluster.com
    secretName: tls-test1-ingress
```

Comment: It's not clear why you need the externalName and can't just call `https://service1.externalservice.com`. What you are describing is a limitation of externalName services, but you can create an istio service definition with host `service1.externalservice.com`, but this seems a bit pointless unless you are using the istio egress gateway to restrict outbound traffic.

Comment: i did try using istio gateways and virtual services, the 2 issues i ran into there is 1 it was a pain to use cert-manager to get letsencrypt certs for service1.mycluster.com using http01 (i cant use dns01) and 2 whenever i called the service via the virtualservice i was getting an error about sending a http request to the https port so seemed that it was ignoring the tls when it forwarded the request and was just using http

Comment: And what's the issue with not using a virtual service or externalName at all and just calling the real URI?

Comment: so the problem with the real URI is we will soon be moving it behind a firewall where our new cluster can still reach it but the public cant but they still need access to some routes on it which is why we want them proxied via the new cluster, it also means that all our apis will be subdomains of the same root domain where currently this legacy api is on an old domain